# Regex to extract a config section containing certain key pair value from a config file

Tags: bash, grep, openwrt

The goal is as the title says. It felt simple at first, but I just couldn't do it by myself.

Here's an example of the file:

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
option type 'mac80211'
option band '2g'

config wifi-iface 'default_radio0'
option device 'radio0'
option mode 'ap'
option ssid '2.4G'
option network 'WLAN'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
option type 'mac80211'
option band '5g'

config wifi-iface 'default_radio1'
option device 'radio1'
option mode 'ap'
option ssid '5G'
```

Basically all I wanted to do was to get the corresponding `device` by `ssid`, and I'm trying to do that with the intermediate step of extracting a config section first. The example is a simplified version of the wireless config on openwrt, but I'm not limited to use the native tool set, as I'm managing these AP remotely.

Consider the ssid `5G`, I get the whole file back with grep -P `(?s)(?=config).*?5G.*?(?=\n\n)`  when I just want

```
config wifi-iface 'default_radio1'
option device 'radio1'
option mode 'ap'
option ssid '5G'
```

I'm already trying something else like splitting the file first but it just doesn't feel necessary and I think I'm missing something. Appreciate any help!

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "?ssid.*5G?;?device?,s/.*'\(.*\)'$/\1/p" Q | ed -s file.txt`

Comment: `awk -v RS= '/ssid.*5G/'`

Comment: @markp-fuso Thx it works. Elegant as well.

Comment: keep in mind that `awk` snippet is very fragile and easy to break; assumes the blank lines have no spaces or tabs; does not verify `ssid` and `5G` are on the same line; will also match on any strings containing `ssid` and/or `5G`, eg, `otherssidXXX` and `stuff_5G_YYY`

Comment: `awk -v RS= "/option ssid '5G'/"` to make it a little bit more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner to split the config file into paragraphs (`$/ = "";`), and print the one with `ssid '5G'`:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = ""; } chomp; if ( m{option ssid .5G.} ) { print "$_\n"; }' test1.cfg
config wifi-iface 'default_radio1'
option device 'radio1'
option mode 'ap'
option ssid '5G'
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-grep` you can read the whole file with `-z` and use `-o` to print only the matches.

Start the match with `config` and match all following lines starting with `option` and then match the last line that contains `ssid '5G'`

```
grep -oPz '(?:^|\n\n)\Kconfig\h.*(?:\noption\h.*)*\noption\hssid\h\x275G\x27.*(?=\n\n|$)' file
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:^|\n\n)` Assert the start of the string or match 2 newlines
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `config\h.*` Match `config`  and the rest of the line
- `(?:\noption\h.*)*` Repeat matching all lines that start with `option`
- `\noption\hssid\h\x275G\x27` Match a newline, then `option ssid '5G'`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?=\n\n|$)` Positive lookahead, assert either 2 newlines or the end of the string

Output

```
config wifi-iface 'default_radio1'
option device 'radio1'
option mode 'ap'
option ssid '5G'
```